# What is the different effect of assigning to vs. initialising static variables in a function?

Tags: c, output

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int print1(void)    
{    
    static int x= 10;

    x+=5;    
    return x;    
}

int print2(void)     
{    
    static int x;

    x = 10;    
    x+= 5;    
    return x;
}

int main()    
{    
    int x;    
    x = print1();    
    x+= print1();    
    x+= print2();     
    x+= print2();    
    printf("%d", x);    
    return 0;    
}
```

My solution:

1. First in print1 statement the value of the will increment by 5 , x will be 15 .
2. Then upon calling print1 function for the 2nd time it will be 15+5=20, since it will hold the previous value.
3. Now for the function print2, it will again initialise the x value with 10, then increment it by 5. Value of x will be 15.
4. for the last statement value of x will be 15+5=20.
5. x=15+20+15+20=70

But the answer is 65. Please correct me where did I go wrong? I even wrote it in my compiler, it is giving output 65, but if change the position of x inside Print2 statement like static int x=10, it is giving different output?

Why this is happening?

Comment: initialisation vs assignment?

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès I note my answer is basically what you commented, I hope you do not mind.

Comment: You have one capital "X" among many lower case "x". I assume that to be a typo. You should [edit] to fix that, if you confirm.

Comment: "for the last statement value of x will be 15+5=20." You seem to be under the impression that `x = 10;` will only happen the first time that `print2` is called. Why?

Comment: OT: In your description you should make clear which `x` you are refering to... there are 3 different variables with the name `x`. Prehaps use a notation like: `print1::x` and `print2::x` and `main::x`

Comment: There are several typos in the posted code, in fact. (`+ =` should not have an intervening space.)

Comment: Yah, I have edited  @Yunnosch.

Comment: @Yunnosch That is ok to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The init of a static variable like `static int x=10;` only happens once per program execution. And that is not like a statement being executed, it is during setup of variables for the program.
The assignment statement `x = 10;` is executed each time the function is executed.
This means the two code versions you discuss are different and especially have different effects on variable values; which in turn explains the different output.